# Activating Emacs' kill-ring in Regex-builder

Tags: emacs, regex

**How can you activate Emacs' kill-ring in Regex-builder?**

My regex `" [a-zA-z/0-9-.]*"` hilights stuff which I want to be removed.
I put the regex to kill ring by `C-c C-w`.
I unsuccessfuly activate the delete -command by pressing `SHIFT-CTRL-META-5` that is how I understand `C-M-%`, and then `ENTER` which gives `replaced 0 occurances`. I should apparently press `!` somewhere.

**Where do you press `!`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that `C-c C-w` copies the quoted regular expression and `query-replace-regexp` seems to only like raw regex.

For example

```
C-M-% "[a-z]+" RET test RET
```

does not work, but

```
C-M-% [a-z]+ RET test RET
```

does work.

I do not know what you are refering to when with the `!` key; have you got the reference material that you are working to?

You will see the same problem defined here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338930/replace-double-backslash-with-single-backslash-in-emacs) with some ideas to solve the problem. Including a reference to [re-builder+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/re-builder+.el) which apparantly has some features which make it play nice with `query-replace-regexp` and the likes.